# Array isn't following curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have set up an array modifier and a bezier curve which the array is following. My spheres aligned themselves in a straight line for the length of the curve, however they are not following the curve exactly.

[image: Array not following curve]

This is not a duplicate. I have followed every answer of the already
posted questions and none of them worked.

[image]

Comment: yes please share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The file doesn't show up in the questions although it says it uploaded.

Comment: I guess you have to edit your question and copy paste the link

Comment: Now it's there... I thought it would upload automatically. Guess I should should pay more attention.

Comment: Fit to curve in the Array modifier is only used to get the length correct. If you want the array to curve with the curve then you need to add an additional Curve Modifier.

Comment: You need to remove the Radius check from Curve deform. Then just adding a Curve modifier and setting the curve will make your array follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a *Curve* modifier and, in this modifier, choose the Bezier Curve as the *Object*
- You've changed the radius of the curve vertices, so select the curve, enter in *Edit* mode, select all, open the 3D view properties panel on the right of the 3d view (press <kbd>N</kbd>), and in *Transform* choose a *Mean Radius* of 1